# Is there a chance that Ubuntu is changing Wifi and Ethernet MAC Addesses? Win10+Ubuntu 16.04 Dual boot

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, mac

I`m studying in a place where the Network Rules are giving permission only for PCs with MAC addresses registered in a whitelist of MAC addresses.

I have a PC with Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on dualboot and my ethernet/wireless card MAC addresses are whitelisted on this Network firewall.

The issue is that in Win 10 I can connect normally on the network, but when I boot in Ubuntu, it seems like I`m blocked by this MAC address restriction.

I saw that windows WOL - Windows`s Wake On Lan thing, but it seems ok.

When I connect Ubuntu on another wireless or wired network, it seems ok also.

Can anyone give me a help? I`m quite new on Ubuntu so anything would be a great help.

Comment: Is it possible that Win10 already has the MAC address and it sees your log in with Ubuntu as a conflict? Does this still happen if you do a full shutdown of Win10 see this reference: https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/ which will release the MAC address from the white list.

Comment: I`ve tried to shutdown or restarting win 10 before opening Ubuntu, but still having this issue... Thanks for your answer! Do you have another thing in mind that could help me?